# Android crashes while using telnet command

Tags: android

I am new to android. I am trying to change the battery level of the emulator . I saw the following [Battery charging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mtQq.png) link

It is opening the telnet client and also "open localhost 5554" is working. 
Also help power is working , but when trying to execute "power status discharging" command the emulator crashes with the close dialog as shown below.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out answer for this question. Actually in the config.xml of the android emulator hw.battery=no , it should be hw.battery=yes. That was the problem why my android emulator was crashing.